# Is there anything like an itemized Overlay for Images?

Tags: android, image

Hi 
I am searching for functionality which works like the itemizedOverlay on the mapview, only for Imageview. So that I can add items on specific locations on the image and trigger actions on tap of the item.

I am building an application for Android where you get Floorplans and on this Floorplan the rooms should be marked and clickable to get more information.

Thank you very much for any help or hint in this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. Both support Z-axis ordering -- later children will appear to float over top of earlier children. Use `setOnClickListener()` to be notified of taps on the items.