# How do I move an Android ImageView in the Z axis?

Tags: android, opengl-es, imageview

Currently the  ImageView (or any other view) has only the setTranslateX and setTranslateY ? But what if I want to move that in the Z axis ? Do I need to use Camera or Matrix ? If so then how ? Give me an example . Is it possible only with OpenGl ? But if so, then how can i use ImageView with OpenGL ES?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything like an itemized Overlay for Images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215424/is-there-anything-like-an-itemized-overlay-for-images)

Comment: Not really , what i am looking for is kind of a gallery where two imageviews are in the front and two are in the -ve Z axis . Not to be confused with StackView though.

Answer (score 1):

Had you actually clicked on [the link I pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215424/is-there-anything-like-an-itemized-overlay-for-images), and read the answers, you would have found [an answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216049/115145). That answer contains the following sentence:

> Use a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. Both support Z-axis ordering -- later children will appear to float over top of earlier children.

Answer (score 0):

`android:elevation` property is what you are looking for.